# C++11 way to reset a struct to null?

Tags: c++, c++11, reset, zero, bullet

I am learning a physics library and it involves creating info structs and then passing them to initialiser functions:

```
btRigidBodyConstructionInfo rbInfo = (/*values...*/);
btRigidBody* rigidBody = new btRigidBody(rbInfo);
```

Now I want to reset the struct (null it) to reuse it. I found another question on SO which is identical, and the answer was either to create a zero-initialised temporary and set it to it, or after C++11:

```
rbInfo = {};
```

When I tried this I got the message:

> "No operator "=" matches these operands.

I was confused and but then found out that this syntax attempts to call the default constructor (at least in my compiler (Visual Studio 2017)), and rbInfo doesn't haven't any. I have a feeling that that syntax does the same as:

```
rbInfo = btRigidBodyConstructionInfo{};
```

In this case is there no way to reset the struct without setting the individual members? I thought about memsetting, but that's a bad idea generally because there might be things like vtable pointers and such, right?

Comment: `... rbInfo = (...);` is unlikely to be any sort of correct. How are you really initializing it?

Comment: If your class has a sensible "empty" state, why not implement a default constructor?

Comment: @Quentin The class is from the Bullet physics library, not mine.

Comment: You can maybe red [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030829/c-is-it-possible-to-set-an-object-to-null) to get some ideas.

Comment: `rbInfo = {};` is not correct syntax, while `rbInfo =  btRigidBodyConstructionInfo{};` will create a temporary object, fill it with zeroes (since `rbInfo` does not have default constructor) and then assign to `rbInfo`.

Comment: @VTT I did test it, and it does seem to work, and then if I make my default constructor unavailable it throws errors. I'm not sure if that answer is incorrect, it is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183429/c-completely-erase-or-reset-all-values-of-a-struct

Comment: @VTT I'm pretty sure it's correct syntax for implicitly-default-constructible objects.

Comment: You seem to mix copy initialization syntax `btRigidBodyConstructionInfo
rbInfo = {};` which is valid with copy assignment syntax `rbInfo = {};` which is not valid. Don't let presence of `=` confuse you.

Comment: The crux of the matter is that you are using MSVC. In any other modern compiler, `rbInfo = {};` should work so long as the default c'tor is not explicit.

Comment: @VTT [I'm not](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b83917bc611476c0) ;)

Comment: @StoryTeller what a cheap jab at MSVC :p -- but the issue here is that `btRigidBodyConstructionInfo` [does not have a default constructor at all](http://bulletphysics.com/Bullet/BulletFull/structbtRigidBody_1_1btRigidBodyConstructionInfo.html)...

Comment: Alright then, I guess one need to always mark default constructors as `explicit` then...

Comment: @StoryTeller Sorry maybe I wasn't clear, the only constructor is one that takes arguments so I assume there is no default constructor. I'm wondering whether there's a way to reset the struct in any way, as neither rbInfo = {}; nor rbInfo = btRigidBodyConstructionInfo{}; works.

Comment: @Quentin - There has to be one to support value initialization. Even for aggregates. And I'ma jab at MSVC until it hurts :P

Comment: @Quentin Yes, I'm sorry if that wasn't clear, no default constructor. On the topic of MSVC, I've often come here with problems only to find that it doesn't conform to some standard...

Comment: @Zebrafish since this class does not provide a default constructor, either it is not meant to have a "default" state, or it is poorly implemented. What use do you make of that "empty" instance? Maybe you should change *that* to not need it?

Comment: @Quentin - And now I entered the link and understood your point. Yes, not default c'tor. This takes me back to my first comment on this post. No way `... rbInfo = (...);` is any sort of correct.

Comment: @Quentin Well I'm just starting out with this library, so I'm figuring out things as I go along. But I guess the answer to my question is that if there's no default constructor it can't be reset in any quick way like {} or something.

Comment: @Zebrafish - If there's no default c'tor, there's no "default state" for you to put the object in. `{}` is not magic.

Comment: If there is only a constructor with parameters, how did you create the "empty" structure?

Comment: If your class doesn't have a default constructor what do you mean by "reset"?   To reset anything, there has to be a specification of what the end state is - and, practically, that will usually mean the same state as a default-constructed object.  If there is no default constructor, you need to specify the required end state,

Comment: @StoryTeller I thought I was wanting to put it in a zero state, not in a default state. But I think you're right. It has values passed to it like mass, where if mass is zero then it's not calculated dynamically, so I wanted to start at null, but it's no big deal. I was curious if there was a way to do this with C++, doesn't seem there is without a default constructor.

Comment: @Zebrafish - Yes, there is no safe way, by design. If a type needs to be initialized a certain way, it's usually for a reason. The language itself won't allow you to default initialize something unless it supports it, either explicitly or implicitly.

Comment: Hi, Is this the header for rigid body? https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/blob/master/src/BulletDynamics/Dynamics/btRigidBody.h
If so I don't think there's a safe way to do what you want and the answer will be create a new object. I'll explain in an answer if that is the header.

Answer (score 4):

Your question sounds a bit like a small [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/201677).

You state your goal is

> Now I want to reset the struct (null it) to reuse it.

The **X** is "reuse the structure," but somehow a **Y** of "reset the structure" got mixed in. If all you want to do is reuse the structure, you can just do this:

```
btRigidBodyConstructionInfo rbInfo = (/*values...*/);
btRigidBody* rigidBody = new btRigidBody(rbInfo);

rbInfo = {/*new values...*/};
```

Or, if your compiler is too old to support that syntax, then:

```
rbInfo = btRigidBodyConstructionInfo(/*new values...*/);
```

Comment: rbInfo = {/* new values...*/}; seems to be easiest.  Yes, I get what you mean, but I was curious about whether the language had any syntax to null out a struct that's already been created, as there seems to be a lot of hidden little features in this language, and also things are added every couple of years and I'm always late to find out.

Comment: @Zebrafish it does, but *only if* that is meaningful for that type. Which is defined by the author of the type, by providing a default constructor and an assignment operator (either or both of which *may* be implicit)

Comment: @Caleth What you're saying is that if the author had any intention of having the struct reset to null values he would have made a default constructor to null all the values? A default constructor doesn't necessarily null the values. If we want to null the values on initialisation you do Foo foo{};, which isn't the default one, I don't think.

Comment: @Zebrafish A constructor is "the default constructor" if it has no parameters. `Foo foo{};` *must* call `Foo`'s default constructor, because it supplies no parameters

Comment: @Zebrafish Nulling values (as in literally zeroing them) of a class object's members makes little sense in C++ in the general case. One of the main features of classes is supporting *invariants* (always having the class in some defined, consistent state). Explicitly zeroing out would go *clearly* against that.

Comment: @Caleth Then there can be more than one default constructor if I call Foo{} and then Foo(), right?

Comment: @Zebrafish both expressions `Foo{}` and `Foo()` create a temporary `Foo` using `Foo::Foo()`. Generally you then do something with that `Foo` before the end of the enclosing statement (like copying it into an existing `Foo` variable), where it ceases to exist (with `Foo::~Foo()` being called)

Comment: @Caleth Right, but this idea of "the default constructor" implying there is only one is not clear, as Foo{} and Foo() both call the default constructor but do entirely different things, the first one being zero-initialised.

Comment: @Zebrafish No, they do not do entirely different things; in fact, they do the exact same thing. `()` and `{}`, when valid as initialisers, both do *value initialisation:* for built-in types, this means zero-initialisation. For classes, this means calling the default ctor.

Comment: You might be confused by aggregate initialization, which is a special case of [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) with the form `Foo foo {}` (or `Foo foo = {}`), however that is a **statement**, not an expression

Comment: @Caleth There's no doubt I'm so confused. However what I should have said is that if the default constructor is compiler-provided, that Foo foo; and Foo foo{}; both call the default constructor and they do different things, Foo foo{} will zero-initialise. "the default constructor" doesn't seem to be just one in this case.

Comment: @Zebrafish The difference is that `Foo foo;` does default-initialisation, while `Foo foo{};` does value-initialisation. IOW, the constructor is the same both times; but the other stuff that happens as part of the initialisation declaration/expression can differ.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ variables have values, not references, backing them.  This is distinct from most other languages, where variables are references to possible values.

Some languages have simple data be actual values, while classes are always references.  Few languages have class objects whose variables are actually the value of the class.

There is no generic "null" state for (all kinds of) values.  Values, in general, are not "nullable".  In C++ you can enforce that a type never holds byte values of `0`.  For example:

```
class Foo {
  Foo(){}
private:
  int x = -1;
};
```

this really simple class can never have its `x` value be `0`.

For some types of values, you can literally zero them out (set all their bytes to zero).  For other types of values, this is explicitly not allowed.

A concept similar to being nullable is being constructible from zero arguments.  If that is the case, and you have a copy or move assign operator, then

```
foo = {};
```

will (usually) assign to `foo` a temporary zero-argument constructed `Foo` (assuming `foo` is of type `Foo`, and sane `operator=` overloads).

If your type `btRigidBodyConstructionInfo` has no zero-argument constructor, and is not an aggregate, then you cannot do `foo = {};` if `foo` is `btRigidBodyConstructionInfo foo;`.

You can do `foo = {construction arguments};`, and assuming a sane `operator=` it will do what you want.

If you want a nullable value type, consider `boost::optional` or `std::optional`.

```
std::optional<btRigidBodyConstructionInfo> foo{ std::in_place, /*values...*/ };
```

then use `*foo` at point of use.  Later, you can null the value by doing `foo={};`.

To repopulate it, you can either use

```
foo = {std::in_place, /*values...*/};
```

or

```
foo.emplace( /*values...*/ );
```

you can test if the `foo` is nulled by doing `if (!foo)`, and you can access the value (undefined behavior if it is null) by `*foo`.

This behaves a bit like a pointer, but it is actually a value type.